# How is this matrix calculated so quickly?

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

I have an exponential matrix:

[image]

I now want to calculate $A^4$. And there is this explanation:
[image]

I dont understand how this was calculated. This has to imply that $A=0$ in the first place if I am correct and how am I supposed to see that? Does this have something to do with the fact that all 4 eigenvalues to A are 0 somehow (due to highest order of polynomial in $e^{tA}$ and no e term there)?

Comment: You can differentiate once to find $A$, and it's not zero.

Comment: $A^4 = 0$ does not imply that $A = 0$. And if we had $A = 0$, then we would've had $e^{tA}$ be the identity. Do you know how $e^{tA}$ is constructed from $A$?

Comment: $A$ is a shift matrix, which is nilpotent

Comment: @Arthur Oh, I see. It is with $e^{tA} = S\begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_1t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{\lambda_2t} \end{bmatrix}S^{-1}$

Comment: No, $A\neq0$. Hint: Write down the definition of the matrix exponential (and compare to Taylor expansion).

Answer (score 2):

If$$f(t)=\exp(tA)=\operatorname{Id}+tA+\frac12(tA)^2+\frac1{3!}(tA)^3+\cdots,$$you have $f(0)=\operatorname{Id}$. Also,$$f'(t)=A+tA^2+\frac12t^2A^3+\frac1{3!}t^3A^4+\cdots=A\exp(tA),$$and therefore $f'(0)=A$. More generally, $f^{(n)}(0)=A^n$. But, in your case, since $f(t)$ is a $4\times 4$ matries whose entries are polynomial functions with degree smaller than $4$, $f^{(4)}(0)=0$; in other words, $A^4=0$. It does *not* follow from this that $A=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand the first part but not so much after $f'(0)=A$ (I understand this). For instance why is $f^{(n)}(0)=A^4$ the case? Do you perhaps mean $f^{(n)}(0)=A^n$?

Comment: Did you understand why $f'(t)=A\exp(tA)$?

Comment: Yes, I understood that part

Comment: So, in particular, $f'(0)=A$. On the other hand,\begin{align}f'(t)=A\exp(tA)&\implies f''(t)=A^2\exp(tA)\\&\implies f^{(3)}(t)=A^3\exp(tA)\\&\implies f^{(4)}(t)=A^4\exp(tA).\end{align}So, $f^{(4)}(0)=A^4$.

Comment: Oh, yes I understand this also now. But what happens after this? I know now that $f^{(4)}(0)=A^4$

Comment: So since my matrix is 4x4, does this mean that the Taylor Expansion only has 4 elements and hence the derivative is 0? I might be completely off course here. Sorry for being dumb

Comment: Since $A^4=0$, the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $0$ is $f(0)+f'(0)+\frac12f''(0)+\frac1{3!}f'''(0)$. Other than that, I don't know what you are trying to deduce.

Comment: @Clone There are plenty of $4\times 4$ matrices with an infinitely long Taylor expansion (the identity matrix, for instance). It is the fact that $A$ is nilpotent that makes the Taylor expansion stop.